What is the infinity category of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$?
Let $\mathcal{J}$ denote the topological category of finite-dimensional real inner product spaces with linear isometric embeddings. The space of morphisms $\mathcal{J}(\mathbb{R}^k, \mathbb{R}^n)$ is the Stiefel manifold of $k$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^n$. By applying the singular complex functor to the mapping spaces we obtain a simplicial category, which by abuse of notation I will also denote by $\mathcal{J}$.
Via the homotopy coherent nerve $N^h : \mathsf{Cat}_\Delta \to \mathsf{sSet}$ we may view the simplicial category $\mathcal{J}$ as a simplicial set (actually a quasi-category).
My questions concern the slice simplicial set (quasi-category) $N^h(\mathcal{J})_{/\mathbb{R}^n}$ given by slicing the homotopy coherent nerve of $\mathcal{J}$ over $\mathbb{R}^n$. One could reasonably describe this as the $\infty$-category of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Question 1: Is $N^h(\mathcal{J})_{/\mathbb{R}^n}$ (equivalent to) a finite simplicial set?

I believe it is certainly a finite-dimensional simplicial set since the simplicies should (roughly) correspond to flags of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Related is the following question.

Question 2: What is the geometric realization of $N^h(\mathcal{J})_{/\mathbb{R}^n}$?

My guess is that $|N^h(\mathcal{J})_{/\mathbb{R}^n}| \simeq D^{\binom{n+1}{2}}$.
The evidence for this is the following observation. Consider the topological poset of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. This defines a category object in topological spaces with space of objects given by a disjoint union of Grassmannian manifolds and space of morphisms given by flags of subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of length $2$. This is the "Grassmannian" poset defined by Vassiliev, see e.g., Example 3.1. of "Combinatorics of Topological Posets" by Živaljević.
This defines a Segal object in topological spaces (by taking the "internal nerve") and the geometric realization of this Segal space may be computed to be homeomorphic to $D^{\binom{n+1}{2}}$. In the same paper, Section 5.1, originally by Vassiliev, they compute the realization of the poset of proper non-zero subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be homemorphic to $S^{\binom{n+1}{2}-2}$, and the result follows by adding the initial and terminal object.
Under the equivalence between (complete) Segal objects in topological spaces with (complete) Segal objects in simplicial sets and hence with quasi-categories I believe that the (internal nerve of the) Grassmannian poset corresponds (up to a zigzag of equivalences) with $N^h(\mathcal{J})_{/\mathbb{R}^n}$.

Don't you need to take away the terminal object $\mathbb R^n$ and the initial object $0$ to get a nontrivial homotopy type?

You're correct. I've corrected the question to reflect this.

It's certainly not a finite simplicial set, since already the mapping spaces in the simplicial category are not finite (they are Sing of positive-dimensional manifolds). You can probably ask whether it is equivalent to a finite simplicial set.

When $n=1$, you should get that $\mathcal N^h(\mathcal J){/\mathbb R^1}$ is equivalent to the opposite of the orbit category $\mathcal O{C_2}$ of the group $C_2$. The representable functor $Hom(-,C_2) : \mathcal O_{C_2}^{op} \to Spaces$ which takes values in finite spaces and has colimit $BC_2$, which is not finite or finitely-dominated. So $\mathcal O_{C_2}^{op}$ is not a finite or finitely-dominated $\infty$-category.
